# Spring OKta requires Full Authentication to access login page in Angular 7

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

I have configured the OKta with reference from the OKTA developer blog using Spring Boot 2 and Angular 7
Reference Link -> https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/22/basic-crud-angular-7-and-spring-boot-2
But I am facing issue while accessing the default page localhost:4200 i.e. login page. It gives the error "*Full authentication is required to access this resource unauthorized*"

I have configured the required dependencies and the code required on the client and the server end. Yet it seems to be giving the unauthorized error.

Gradle Dependencies:

```
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core -> 5.1.3.RELEASE
org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security -> 3.0.6.RELEASE
org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:3.3.0
org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:3.3.0
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security -> 2.1.2.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.3.RELEASE
com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:1.2.1
com.okta.spring:okta-spring-security-oauth2:1.2.1
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.3.RELEASE (*)
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.5.RELEASE -> 2.1.2.RELEASE (*)
org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.3.
org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.2.RELEASE
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CustomFilter customFilter() {
        return new CustomFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(customFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()           
            .permitAll()
            //.fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().cors().and()
            .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

CustomFilter.java

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "authorization, content-type, xsrf-token, Cache-Control, remember-me, WWW-Authenticate");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
}
```

App.module.ts
imports

```
import { OktaAuthModule } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './shared/okta/auth.interceptor';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
}];

const config = {
  issuer: 'https://dev-xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/implicit/callback',
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}; //I have added same code in yml as well
imports [
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, useHash: true}),
OktaAuthModule.initAuth(config),
]
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
...
{ path: 'implicit/callback', component: OktaCallbackComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

As soon as the angular server is up, it should redirect me to the login page but it gives the error "*Full authentication is required to access this resource unauthorized*"

Curl Error

```
curl -v -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"  "http://localhost:4200"
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:4200/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4200 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4200
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Powered-By: Express
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
< access-control-allow-headers: authorization, content-type, xsrf-token, Cache-Control, remember-me, WWW-Authenticate
< access-control-expose-headers: xsrf-token
< access-control-allow-credentials: true
< access-control-max-age: 180
< pragma: no-cache
< www-authenticate: Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"
< cache-control: no-store
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-frame-options: DENY
< content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 17:17:11 GMT
< connection: close
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I have done everything by the article yet it seems to be failing.

Comment: I'd suggest cloning the blog post's GitHub repo and following the instructions in its README to configure it for your Okta org. https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-7-example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to edit your Okta app adding **redirect URIs**

[image]